# How to get value stored in a linq call Expression

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I extend Dynamic.cs to qualify it for usage with indexers. In this scenario I need to get the index, which is stored in a call expression. In the debugger, I can see:

```
 -      left    {Param_0.get_Item(0)}   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression {System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN}
    -   Arguments   Count = 1   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TrueReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>}
        -   [0] {0} System.Linq.Expressions.Expression {System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression}
            CanReduce   false   bool
            DebugView   "0" string
            NodeType    Constant    System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType
            + Type  {Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
            Value   0   object {int}
    +   Rohdatenansicht
```

**What I want is:**

```
left.Arguments[0].Value
```

How can I get this?

An ugly method will be perhaps to use left.ToString(). This will result in: "Param_0.get_Item(0)" There I can extract the parameter of get_Item(). But I think this is not the right way.

Comment: @svick Do you know google ;). If not, look there: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to that value, you just need to cast the expressions to the right types:

```
Expression left = …

var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)left;

var constant = (ConstantExpression)methodCall.Arguments[0];

int value = (int)constant.Value;
```

Alternatively, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dynamicLeft = left;

int value = dynamicLeft.Arguments[0].Value;
```